# How do you get lat long info using navigator.geolocation when connecting to 192.168.x.x

Tags: jquery, android, geolocation, navigator, w3c-geolocation

I'm trying to set up a purely local wireless LAN with no access to the wider internet. i.e. all websites are served from hosts via 192.168.x.x addresses.

One host (192.168.1.100) is serving a webpage with this kind of javascript in it:

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,errorPosition,{ enableHighAccuracy:true });

and I'm connecting to this host using an Android phone. (The aim is to extract the phone's GPS position and upload it to the host for display on Google Earth there via a KML file).

The Browser app on Android does provide a location to this same application when it's accessed on a WAN via a named server like http://example.com/locationtest.html but when I disconnect from the WAN, and connect to the local-only LAN and load the same page then navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition appears not to work.

Ideas? Known prohibitions? Methods to debug this issue? (we don't have a nice javascript debugger on the device itself... is there a way to fake the way this device will respond on a desktop?)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue lies with geolocation; in that it's used for more than just GPS.  I know that you set enableHighAccuracy to true; which should force GPS *if the device has it*, but depending on how the browser implements getCurrentPosition; it may refuse to work if there's no geolocation database to connect to.

You could try setting maximumAge very high to use cached data or set timeout to zero force GPS or something along those lines; but you may not get consistent results across all of the Android browsers.

Actually; I'm a bit surprised you have this issue.  I'm sure I read User Cases on the W3C Geolocation API Specification that described offline scenarios.  You should try displaying the data returned from the PositionError interface and see if you can get some more information.